# How to find the location of an error when line numbers cannot be used

Tags: javascript, debugging, onerror

I am finding it difficult to locate where an error occurs in javascript on a client I have no access to. Currently I trap the error with onerror and send the arguments to a log on the server.

Unfortunately the line number is no help because numerous javascript files get included, causing the line number to not correspond to anything I have access to.

So if I get something like "n is not defined", and n occurs many times in the function, I have no way to locate where it happened.

I have been trying to reference the code on the line throwing the error say "x=n * 5 + 4", then I could search for that code, but have had no luck referencing the actual code on a line from within javascript.

So how does one locate the line that threw the error in this situation?

- client uses firefox only, if that matters.
- I have no access to client
- This is not one error I am stuck on, but working on how to track an error in this situation

Comment: I'm assuming you also don't have access to source maps?

Comment: Don't think I can use them, as some code is dynamically generated

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use Firefox's debugger.

1. Open dev tools
2. Go to the debugger, select the .js file you want, and hit the little `{}` button in the bottom left (depending on version yours may be in a different location) -- this will prettify the JavaScript
3. Set breakpoints by clicking next to line numbers

From here on out you have to do this old-fashioned. Cast a breakpoint net around your trouble code, then keep narrowing down the lines until you find the occurrence that causes the error.

Of course, once you find the line it still won't be 1-to-1 with the original code, but hopefully the breakpoint exercise will at least reduce the *scope* of code/logic you have to dig through.

Comment: But you have access to code and know the client's browser specs, correct? Assuming the client hasn't messed with anything, you should be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: First I need to know what the issue is :), an error "somewhere in the code" does not help

Comment: Wow. That's...depressing. The first step then should be to try to reproduce the same error, however you can. Use firefox and mess with your site until you get undefined. That's about all I can suggest.

Comment: Haha yea, looking back I completely misread the question. Unfortunately there's not much you can do as you probably already know. It's client side, out of your control, so try to avoid that with good testing before stuff goes out the door :)

Answer (score 0):

use your debugger to enable breaking on error. once you break, look at your locals for clues about your location. go up the stack and look at each frame.

you should be able to trace `n` up the stack and find out why it was null

the little {} that william suggested is also helpful

Comment: Note the point about "no access to client" My problem is not the error, it is the trapping of errors on remote clients, that I am working on.